# Дебажить SQL CRL процедуру

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, отладка, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

Разрабатываю одну SQL CLR процедуру в VisualStudio Premium 2013, SQL Server 2008 R2 локально установлен. Необходимо продебажить CLR код, но что-то никак не выходит. Точки останова (break points) игнорируются. Скрипты, которые вызывают CLR процедуру, запускал и из vs студии, и из sql management студии. Также установил в настройках проекта во вкладке Debbug стартовую акцию - "запуск скрипта", который запускает эту процедуру. Но дебагер тогда скачет (F11) по sql командам, а мне нужно по CLR-коду.

Что нужно сделать что бы дебагер в студии наконец подключился к процессу, выполняющему CLR?

Answer (score 2):

Закрыто, решение нашел здесь: http://www.msdr.ru/47/
То что я должен был сделать, так это "Allow SQL/CLR Debugging" для сервера в окне "SQL Server Object Explorer"